# How to join 3 tables in the sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I want to retrieve the data from the 3 tables in my database. The URL is this: `http://localhost:9000/applications/data/6` where 6 is the ID of the user.

My shareData table looks like this: [image]

I should get all three rows from my database as ID 6 appears in the 1st and 2nd rows of the userID column and in the 3rd row as well, as it is also available in the sharedUser column. But the issue is I am getting only 1 record if I hit the endpoint.

I have changed the type of sharedUser column from json to jsonb and I have tried with below query:

```
const sharedData = await this.shareRepository.findAll({
      attributes: ['userID', 'sharedUser', 'roomId', 'applicationId'],
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          { userID: userId },
          Sequelize.where(
            Sequelize.literal(
              `jsonb_extract_path_text("sharedUser", 'id')::integer`
            ),
            userId
          ),
        ],
      },

      include: [
        {
          model: Application,
          required: true,
          attributes: [
            ... columns from the table
          ],
        },
        {
          model: User,
          required: true,
          where: { id: userId },
          attributes: [...columns from the table],
        },
      ],
    });
```

I have tried above query but it is giving the only first 2 row's data. I want the 3rd row as well.

EDIT: If I remove the square-brackets from my sharedUser column's data and the include part as well from the query then it gives me the data in the console.

Here is the raw SQL query:

```
    Executing (default): SELECT "Share"."id", "Share"."userID", "Share"."sharedUser", "Share"."roomId", "Share"."applicationId", "application"."id" AS "application.id", "application"."applicationType" AS "application.applicationType", 
    "application"."isForward" AS "application.isForward", "application"."applicationStatus" AS "application.applicationStatus", "application"."applicationTitle" AS "application.applicationTitle", "application"."applicationContent" AS "application.applicationContent", "user"."id" AS "user.id", "user"."firstName" AS "user.firstName", "user"."lastName" AS "user.lastName", "user"."isActive" AS "user.isActive" FROM "netabe_shareData" AS "Share" INNER JOIN "netabe_application" AS "application" ON "Share"."applicationId" = "application"."id" 
INNER JOIN "netabe_user" AS "user" ON "Share"."userID" = "user"."id" AND "user"."id" = '6' WHERE ("Share"."userID" = '6' OR "Share"."sharedUser" IN ('{"id":"6"}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to return the data this look quite confusing, if you re using postgres, how about first try to query the data you want like this, i am giving the example in javascript:

```js
  const sharedData = await this.shareRepository.findAll({
       attributes: ['userID', 'sharedUser', 'roomId', 'applicationId'],
       where: {
           [Op.or]: [
               { userID: userId },
               { sharedUser: Sequelize.literal(`"sharedUser"->>'id' = '${userId}'`)} //or only literal if you use destructuring when importing Sequelize
           ]
       }
  });
```

this should let you pick your row's data on userID column or id field from your sharedUser column.

Comment: I have tried this solution as well but no luck. I am getting only first 2 rows where userID 6 is matched but I didn't got the last row in my response.

Comment: Did you try to clean up and remove some code and try to do only the query ? I test on a similar database like yours and it work, even the answer from Anatoly work as well and is even easier, so your problem is somewhere else and you have to debug it by isolating your code.

Comment: Yes, I removed the entire database and added data from the scratch and I also removed the include part as well and then I logged it but in the log it displays only 2 records

Comment: I can't really tell since i can't reproduce the issue, did you test your endpoint in Postman for ex and return simply your sharedData and you still get only 2 records ?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the API in the postman and it returns oly 2 documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Sequelize.literal`:

```js
where: {
           [Op.or]: [
               { userID: userId },
               Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal(`"sharedUser"->>'id'`), '=',userId)
           ]
       }
```

Comment: I have tried this against the json datatype but I got only first 2 rows. I didn't got the last one which is I want to achieve.

Comment: Can you add the generated SQL to the post?

Comment: I have added the query please have a look

Comment: I changed the answer as well